Instead of updating, a new post is being created
I'm working on a small CRUD site, and I ran into a problem: when trying to update an existing post, a new one gets created instead of modifying the existing one.
The ID is being passed correctly, I’ve checked that.
@PostMapping("/edit/{id}")
    public String blogPostEdit(@PathVariable(value = "id") long id,@RequestParam String title, @RequestParam String summary, @RequestParam String fullText, /*@AuthenticationPrincipal MyAppUser currentUser,*/ Model model){
        Blog blog = blogRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow();
        blog.setTitle(title);
        blog.setSummary(summary);
        blog.setFullText(fullText);
        blogRepository.save(blog);
        return "redirect:/home";
    }

Here is the Blog class. If you need any additional code, let me know and I'll send it.
@Entity
public class Blog {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String title;
    private String summary;
    private String fullText;
    private String author;
    private int views;

    public Blog() {
    }

    public Blog(String title, String summary, String fullText, String author) {
        this.title = title;
        this.summary = summary;
        this.fullText = fullText;
        this.author = author;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }

    public void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }

    public String getFullText() {
        return fullText;
    }

    public void setFullText(String fullText) {
        this.fullText = fullText;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public int getViews() {
        return views;
    }

    public void setViews(int views) {
        this.views = views;
    }
}


Everything looks fine. Try to log executed SQL.

For modification of existing entity you should use PUT mapping instead of POST.

I see no SQL above. Is the  tag really relevant?

We don't see what the blogRepository#save() method does, which is pretty important.
